# Carecter reemplazado por un signo de pregunta

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla php hecha con bootstrap y hay un símbolo que es reemplazado por un rombo con signo de pregunta y no se como hacer que funcione.

[image: Error simbolo]

Probe con esto en el header.html y no funciona:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Y también probe con esto y no paso nada

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tus echos de php deben llevar utf8_encode para que pueda transmitir los datos aceptando mas tipos de caracteres.

```
<?php
  $text = "\xE0";
  echo utf8_encode($text);
?>
```

un análisis y conversación mas profunda del porque te aparecian esos simbolos puedes encontrarla aquí:
[¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

pero en resumen: "El contenido se compone de una secuencia de caracteres. Los caracteres representan letras del alfabeto, puntuación, etc. Pero el contenido se almacena en un ordenador como una secuencia de bytes, que son valores numéricos. A veces se utiliza más de un byte para representar un único carácter. Al igual que los códigos utilizados en el espionaje, la forma en que la secuencia de bytes se convierte en caracteres depende de la clave que se haya utilizado para codificar el texto. En este contexto, esa clave se denomina codificación de caracteres." y si la codificación no es la correcta para el texto que se esta utilizando, o que fue extraído, o en el camino se le cambio la codificación. simplemente se mutara la cadena de string y veras símbolos que son ilegibles y que corresponden a sus valores ASCII en la mayoría de las veces
fuente: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings.es

también en esta publicación puedes encontrar mas detalles sobre cuando usar utf8_enconde y cuando utf8_decode
[¿Cuándo usar utf8_encode o utf8_decode?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29662/cu%C3%A1ndo-usar-utf8-encode-o-utf8-decode)

por ultimo, debes saber que PHP también tiene una configuración de codificación seteada por defecto, la cual puedes cambiar de forma muy simple. te dejo el link de la documentación al respecto
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: Si hubieras leído el artículo recomendado por @Triby (arriba) antes de responder, seguro que no habrías escrito esta respuesta, porque resuelve un caso local **dejando vivo el problema de fondo**.

Comment: disculpa, la verdad yo habia respondido antes que el. ahora mismo modifico mi respuesta. gracias

Comment: Si la modificas solo ten en cuenta el punto acerca de la configuración global de php que es el que afecta tu respuesta. Pero lo que le sirvio al OP déjalo. Es una idea que funciona para muchos que le temen a tocar las configuraciones. Por eso no te califiqué mal.

Comment: listo, gracias :)

Comment: Muy buena aclaración. Y, la profundización hecha es impportante (+1)